# `SwaggerRequestExample` is being ignored

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-2.0, swashbuckle

As I was adding swagger to my API, I wanted to get default values and response examples. I added the NuGet packages and tried to follow [this tutorial](https://mattfrear.com/2016/01/25/generating-swagger-example-requests-with-swashbuckle/). The `SwaggerResponseExample` attribute works properly but the `SwaggerRequestExample` seems to be simply ignored.

With my action defined as follow

```
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(int), typeof(PersonExamples.Request))]
[SwaggerResponseExample(200, typeof(PersonExamples.Response))]
/* more attribute & stuff */
public IActionResult Get(int id) { /* blabla */ }
```

The `PersonExamples` class being defined as follow (non-revelant code removed)

```
public class PersonExamples
{
    public class Request : IExamplesProvider
    {
        public object GetExamples() { return _persons.List().First().Id; }
    }

    public class Response : IExamplesProvider
    {
        public object GetExamples() { return _persons.List().First(); }
    }
}
```

Here is also the relevant part of the `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(conf =>
    {
        conf.SwaggerDoc(_documentationPrefix, new Info
        {
            Title = "Global",
            Version = "v0",
        });

        conf.OperationFilter<ExamplesOperationFilter>();

        var filePath = Path.Combine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath, "Global.xml");
        conf.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
    });

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSwagger(opt =>
    {
        opt.RouteTemplate = "{documentName}/swagger.json";
    });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwaggerUI(conf =>
        {
            conf.SwaggerEndpoint($"/{_documentationPrefix}/swagger.json", "DataService API");
            conf.RoutePrefix = "doc/swagger";
        });
    }
}
```

When I run my project and go to the swagger.json page I notice that the response example is properly written, but the request example is nowhere to be found. After further debugging, I notice that a breakpoint placed in `PersonExamples.Response.GetExamples` will be hit when the page is called, but one placed in the `PersonExamples.Request.GetExamples` method won't. So i believe that the `SwaggerRequestExample` attribute never calls the method and may not even be called itself.

Did I improperly used the tag ? Why is it never called ?

Comment: Are you using the NuGet packages, or did you try implementing the code manually? If you're not using the NuGet package, I'd suggest trying that first, as there may be a subtle bug in the example code that wouldn't necessarily be present in the actual code that's published.

Comment: I'm using the NuGet package.

Comment: Have you managed to work this out? I'm having the exact same problem with a POST Method...

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old, but Swagger Examples don't support GET request parameters (query parameters). It only works when the parameters are in the request body (eg: POST requests)