# SwaggerRequestExample attribute does not work in ASP.NET MVC 5 (.NET Framework 4.5.2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.examples

I am toying with [Swashbuckle.Examples package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.Examples/) (3.10.0) in an ASP.NET MVC project. However, I cannot make request examples appear within the UI.

**Configuration** (SwaggerConfig.cs)

```
public static void Register()
{
    var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
        .EnableSwagger(c => {
             c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "TestApp.Web");
             c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\TestApp.Web.xml", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
             c.OperationFilter<ExamplesOperationFilter>();
             c.OperationFilter<DescriptionOperationFilter>();
             c.OperationFilter<AppendAuthorizeToSummaryOperationFilter>();
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c => { });
 }
```

**Request example classes**

```
public class EchoRequestExample : IExamplesProvider
{
    public object GetExamples()
    {
        return new EchoInput { Value = 7 } ;
    }
}

public class EchoInput
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Action**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Echo")]
[CustomApiAuthorize]
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(EchoInput), typeof(EchoRequestExample))]
[ResponseType(typeof(EchoServiceModel))]
public HttpResponseMessage Echo([FromUri] EchoInput model)
{
    var ret = new EchoServiceModel
    {
        Username = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name,
        Value = value
    };
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ret);
}
```

Swagger UI shows xml comments and output metadata (model and an example containing default values), but shows no request example. I attached to process and `EchoRequestExample.GetExamples` is not hit.

**Question:** How to make SwaggerRequestExample attribute work in ASP.NET MVC 5?

*Note:* Windows identity is used for authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the feeling, lot's of overhead just for an example, I struggle with this for a while, so I created my own fork of swashbuckle, and after unsuccessful attempts to merge my ideas I ended up detaching and renaming my project and pushed to nuget, here it is: [Swagger-Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/)

An example like that will be:

```
    [SwaggerExample("id", "123456")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
```

Here the full code for that: [Swagger_Test/Controllers/IHttpActionResultController.cs#L26](https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/e887ec937afd309cc8c7c2b1c32b338e4568305c/Swagger_Test/Controllers/IHttpActionResultController.cs#L26)

Wondering how that looks like on the Swagger-UI, here it is:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=IHttpActionResult#/IHttpActionResult/IHttpActionResult_GetById

Comment: I do not mind the overhead since my goal is to provide a list of examples. However, did you manage to make it work using  Swashbuckle.Examples? I will try your library anyway.

Comment: On my library I merged most of the functionality provided by Swashbuckle.Examples, if there is something I'm missing that you need let me know and I can add it.

Comment: I think `SwaggerRequestExample` is missing. While it requires more code, it provides a way to specify a dynamic list of examples.

Comment: SwaggerExample should do what you need instead of SwaggerRequestExample

Comment: It seems that `SwaggerRequestExample ` is messed up also on [ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875059/swaggerrequestexample-is-being-ignored)

Comment: Look at my test: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index in there you should find simple, complex examples, default values, descriptions with markup, parameters with regex, max and min... let me know if you need something specific

Comment: @LarsTech why don't you ask a proper question here on StackOverflow instead of adding a comment?

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer from library owner [here](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.Examples/issues/39):

> Swagger request examples can only set on [HttpPost] actions

It is not clear if this is a design choice or just a limitation, as I find [HttpGet] examples also relevant.

Comment: He is right! Officially (per the OpenApi Specification 2.0) there are no examples on the get... but for a while now everyone has been using `x-example` just like I showed in my answer