# Specify request model type for swagger. ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I use a custom model binder to bind the request body to the endpoint parameter. The parameter is `CartItem`, and I want to specify the input model type `CartItemRequest` for Swagger. Can I use something similar to [ProducesResponseType] attribute but for request type?

```
 [HttpPut("put-item/{customerId}")]
 [ProducesResponseType(400)]
 [ProducesResponseType(404)]
 [ProducesResponseType(200)]
 public async Task<IActionResult> PutItemToCart(
   [GuidId] Guid customerId, 
   [FromBody] CartItem item) // I want to show CartItemRequest in swagger instead of CartItem
 {
       // some code
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`[SwaggerRequestExample]` might be helpful to solve your problem. First of all, you need to install [`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters/) NuGet Package.

The next step is to register the needed dependencies:

```
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters;

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.ExampleFilters();
});

builder.Services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblyOf<Program>();
```

The example class that implements `IExamplesProvider<TRequestExample>` is required to be created:

```
public class ExampleRequestProvider : IExamplesProvider<ExampleInput>
{
    public ExampleInput GetExamples()
    {
        return new ExampleInput();
    }
}

public class ExampleInput
{
    public int ExampleValue { get; set; }
}

public class ActualInput
{
    public int ActualValue { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, you need to add `[SwaggerRequestExample]` to your endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(ExampleInput), typeof(ExampleRequestProvider))]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] ActualInput actualInput)
{
    return NoContent();
}
```

It was successfully tested for `ASP.NET Core 7.0`, here is the result:

[image: Example Request Provided]

You could also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51652559/swaggerrequestexample-attribute-does-not-work-in-asp-net-mvc-5-net-framework-4), if you faced some problems.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33921013)

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand thank you for the advice. The answer has been updated according to your comment